# Python: Package to reduce size of Floats and Ints?

Tags: python, numpy, pyinstaller

I have a pickle file which is ~550MB containing one huge dict with a few subdictionaries, list of floats and ints; after loading it the required RAM is around 2.5GB.

The required precision for the lists of floats is maximum 10 digits, hence Numpy float16 would be sufficient. When I converted the lists from native Python 64bit Floats to Float16 I saved an incredible amount of RAM - but unfortunately I want to distribute my tool as an exe, hence bundle it using PyInstaller -> But bundling numpy with it makes the .exe huge, it is about 130MB in size. I don't need anything else from Numpy, would just like to store all the lists of Ints and floats using the numpy Datatypes and therefore use np.asarray().

Any ideas on how to get around it?

I was thinking whether there's a **small** module which implements simplified datatypes like Float16 by numpy which I could use, and I was hoping that bundling this module would only take a small amount of RAM.

Do you know something like this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In case it is an object that can be JSON serialized, JSON objects are typically more compact than pickle (but as said before you lose some flexibility).

Comment: The precision of a float16 is 10 bits, not 10 digits.

Comment: Maybe my post was a bit misleading, the storage size on disk is not the problem - the problem is the size of the dictionary in my RAM. I'd like to reduce the required amount of RAM. Maybe I should instead think of another datastructure, hmmm. @Klaus D.: Thanks, yes

Comment: @tim, a possible solution is out-of-core processing, so RAM is not a limiting factor. While your data is currently stored in dictionaries, you may have to refactor to have your data in one large array. In this situation, HDF5 is a very good choice and is supported well by python (h5py and pyTables libraries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if those are really the only two things from numpy you need, what about:

```
from numpy import float16 as NPfloat16
from numpy import asarray as NPasarray

test = [0.12345, 0.98765]
np_test = NPasarray(test, dtype=NPfloat16)

np_test
```

Output =

`array([ 0.12347412,  0.98779297], dtype=float16)`

Will that reduce the size for your exe?

Comment: No, unfortunately not. I guess pyInstaller will pack all the dependencies into the exe and it's hard to figure out which modules it needs and which it dont.

Comment: Shame, but it was worth a shot

Comment: Python is not as simple as you might think. Using Numpy is not really the solution, it would actually increase your memory usage. For example:
```
import sys
import numpy as np
sys.getsizeof(42.42)
>>> 24
sys.getsizeof(np.asarray(42.42, dtype='float32'))
>>> 84
sys.getsizeof(np.asarray(42.42, dtype='float16'))
>>> 82
```